# Regarding microsoft graph Api integration

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to integrate graph.microsoft API into my learning system. Is it possible to open teams scheduled meeting in teams with our domain name? please help me to integrate

Comment: Hi @Ramesh - Could you please explain your query briefly?

Comment: Hi @Ramesh - Are you trying to replace the Microsoft domain name with your own domain in meeting url.

Comment: Hi@Mamatha-MSFT i want like this https://mydomain.teams.microsoft.com/
is it possible?
one other application have this option

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to open teams scheduled meeting in teams with your own domain name.

Comment: Thanks@Mamatha-MSFT